# Redisplay Captcha on form error in Ajax form submit

Tags: 7, ajax, captcha

I have a Fancybox form and the form is sent via Ajax. I know that there is the error about "reuse attack" for Captcha, but this is not my case.

When I wrong the form (some required fields missing) I see the fieldset of Captcha, but no Captcha inside. It's empty.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You could try to ensure that the form fields get validated via JS and prevent the form submission accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If user can submit the form when there is no captcha after errors, it's by design. In captcha settings you checked an option to only verify humanity of an user once. User gets validated as a human on first, failed submit, and is not bothered any more on that form. Go to captcha settings and make him validate each and every time and it will not disappear, but your users will not love you.